# BufferedWriter#write(int) javadoc query

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, bufferedwriter

The [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) for this says:

**Only the lower two bytes of the integer oneChar are written.**

What effect, if any, does this have on writing non-utf8 encoded chars which have been cast to an int?

Update:

The code in question receives data from a socket and writes it to a file. (A lot of things happen between receiving and writing, so I can't just use the string I get using BufferedReader#readLine()). I was using Writer#write(char[]) but this meant I had to create a new char array each time. To get around creating an array everytime, I had a single char array which is filled with -1 (cast to a char).

I then use [TextUtils#getChars](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#getChars(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20char[],%20int)) to fill it, expanding the array if necessary. For writing, I loop through the array, writing to the Writer until char[i] == (char) -1 == true.

Comment: I don't understand your update. TextUtils#getChars takes its input from a CharacterSequence. Why don't you write the CharacterSequence directly using  Writer#append(CharSequence)?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to read using Reader#readLine(), then write using Writer.append. If you cannot do this because of the way your code works, you'll need to post a self-contained code example for your problem. Otherwise it's impossible to understand your constraints and find a different solution.

Comment: Writer#append(charsequence) uses toString before writing, I don't want to create a new string each time. Between readline() and writing to a file, a parser is used to parse the string, add formatting and do various operations on the string. The writing happens only in certain circumstances which are determined by the app state and the type of message, so it has to happen from within the parser. My question is simply can I take the chars from a, say iso-8859-1 encoded string, cast them to an int without losing any data.

Answer (score 0):

Internally,  `write(int)` will just cast its parameter to `char`, so `write(i)` is equivalent to `write((char)i)`.

Now in Java, internally `char` is just an integer type, with the range 0-65535 (i.e. 16 bit). The cast int -> char is a "narrowing primitive conversion" ([Java Language spec, 5.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.3)), and `int` is a signed integer, hence:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed
>   integer to an integral type T simply
>   discards all but the n lowest order
>   bits, where n is the number of bits
>   used to represent type T. In addition
>   to a possible loss of information
>   about the magnitude of the numeric
>   value, this may cause the sign of the
>   resulting value to differ from the
>   sign of the input value.

That's why the Javadoc says that only the lower two bytes are written.

Now, what this means in terms of characters depends on how you want to interpret the int values. A `char` in Java represents a Unicode code point in UTF-16, that is the 16 bit number represented by the char is interpreted as the number of the Unicode code point. So if each of your int values is the number of a 16 bit code point, you're fine (actually, this is only true for characters in the BMP; if you use characters in the supplementary planes, each Unicode code point will be encoded into two `char`s). If it's anything else (including a code point with more than 16 bit, or a negative number, or something else entirely), you'll get garbage.

> What effect, if any, does this have on
>   writing non-utf8 chars which have been
>   cast to an int?

There is no such thing as a "non-utf8 char". UTF-8 is an *encoding*, that is a way to represent a Unicode code point, so the question as posed is meaningless. Maybe you could explain what your code does?